# Overlapping image not properly displayed on all formats

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a graph which consists of 2 images: 1 background image and one image containing the actual data points. The data points image show be aligned at the top of the background image.

The layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/graphImageWrap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/graphImageBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/stroom_grafiek"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/graphImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/graphImageBackground"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/stroom_grafiek"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This works well on a HDPI device:
[image: HDPI]

But on a MDPI device it doesn't align properly:
[image: MDPI]

I hope someone can explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a FrameLayout instead, and make sure the images are the same size.

Comment: Changing LinearLayout to Framelayout and adding android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal" gives me exactly the same result. The width of the images are the same, but the height cannot be the same.

Comment: you need some way to align the height. either align it to the center of the image, or to the bottom, or the top - but if the images themselves are not aligned, you'll get this problem.

Comment: This is what I'm doing with android:layout_alignParentTop="true" and android:layout_alignTop="@id/graphImageBackground", right?